How can I optimise this SQL GROUP BY to remove duplicates, summing on numeric fields?
I am running the following query:
/*Put the grouped data into a temp table */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _TEMP_FORECAST_PARTITION_DATA

SELECT 
    SCENARIO, PERIOD, DEPARTMENT, ACCOUNT, CATEGORY, CURRENCY,
    PROJECT, PARTNERSHIP, EMPLOYEE, BOOKING_DATE, ORIGINAL_CURRENCY, 
    ANALYSIS_COMMENT, COMMENT_TYPE, NOTE, ALLOCATION_EXPLAINER, 
    PIPELINE_VALUATION_DATE, PIPELINE_PROBABILITY, TECH_ORIGINAL_USER,
    TECH_ORIGINAL_ORIGIN, TECH_ORIGINAL_DATEUPD, DEPARTMENT_VISIBILITY,
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT,
    SUM(ORIGINAL_AMOUNT) AS ORIGINAL_AMOUNT
INTO 
    _TEMP_FORECAST_PARTITION_DATA
FROM 
    AW_FCT_000002_000001
GROUP BY    
    SCENARIO, PERIOD, DEPARTMENT, ACCOUNT, CATEGORY, CURRENCY,
    PROJECT, PARTNERSHIP, EMPLOYEE, BOOKING_DATE, ORIGINAL_CURRENCY,
    ANALYSIS_COMMENT, COMMENT_TYPE, NOTE, ALLOCATION_EXPLAINER,
    PIPELINE_VALUATION_DATE, PIPELINE_PROBABILITY, TECH_ORIGINAL_USER,
    TECH_ORIGINAL_ORIGIN, TECH_ORIGINAL_DATEUPD, DEPARTMENT_VISIBILITY

/* Clear the original source table, then populate it with the temp table */

TRUNCATE TABLE AW_FCT_000002_000001

INSERT INTO AW_FCT_000002_000001
(OID, SCENARIO, PERIOD, DEPARTMENT, ACCOUNT, CATEGORY, CURRENCY,
   PROJECT, PARTNERSHIP, EMPLOYEE, BOOKING_DATE, ORIGINAL_CURRENCY, ANALYSIS_COMMENT,
   COMMENT_TYPE, NOTE, ALLOCATION_EXPLAINER, PIPELINE_VALUATION_DATE,
   PIPELINE_PROBABILITY, AMOUNT, ORIGINAL_AMOUNT, 
   TECH_ORIGINAL_USER, TECH_ORIGINAL_ORIGIN, 
   TECH_ORIGINAL_DATEUPD, DEPARTMENT_VISIBILITY)

SELECT
    NEWID(), SCENARIO, PERIOD, DEPARTMENT, ACCOUNT, CATEGORY, CURRENCY,
    PROJECT, PARTNERSHIP, EMPLOYEE, BOOKING_DATE, ORIGINAL_CURRENCY,
    ANALYSIS_COMMENT, COMMENT_TYPE, NOTE, ALLOCATION_EXPLAINER,
    PIPELINE_VALUATION_DATE, PIPELINE_PROBABILITY, 
    AMOUNT, ORIGINAL_AMOUNT, TECH_ORIGINAL_USER,
    TECH_ORIGINAL_ORIGIN, TECH_ORIGINAL_DATEUPD, DEPARTMENT_VISIBILITY
FROM 
    _TEMP_FORECAST_PARTITION_DATA

The query is taking 20 minutes to run - is there a more efficient way to do this?
There's no functional issue, but it seems to take a disproportionate amount of time to other things I'm doing with the table.
Query execution plan here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HydaVBp2C
Statistics from the run:
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 5 ms.
(54830198 rows affected)
(1 row affected)
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 1852172 ms,  elapsed time = 544239 ms.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 79 ms,  elapsed time = 75 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 7 ms.
(54830198 rows affected)
(1 row affected)
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 348640 ms,  elapsed time = 405714 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Completion time: 2024-09-10T06:00:59.0020584+01:00
Table definition as follows:
USE [TGK04_DATA_002]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AW_FCT_000002_000001]    Script Date: 9/10/2024 3:06:40 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AW_FCT_000002_000001](
    [OID] [varchar](36) NOT NULL,
    [SCENARIO] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [PERIOD] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [DEPARTMENT] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ACCOUNT] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CATEGORY] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CURRENCY] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [PROJECT] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [PARTNERSHIP] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [EMPLOYEE] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [BOOKING_DATE] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [AMOUNT] [numeric](27, 9) NULL,
    [ORIGINAL_AMOUNT] [numeric](27, 9) NULL,
    [ORIGINAL_CURRENCY] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [NOTE] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [ANALYSIS_COMMENT] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [PIPELINE_VALUATION_DATE] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [COMMENT_TYPE] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [TECH_ORIGINAL_USER] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [TECH_ORIGINAL_ORIGIN] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [TECH_ORIGINAL_DATEUPD] [datetime] NULL,
    [ALLOCATION_EXPLAINER] [varchar](2000) NULL,
    [PIPELINE_PROBABILITY] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DEPARTMENT_VISIBILITY] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DAY_RATE] [numeric](27, 9) NULL,
    [DAY_RATE_ORIGINAL_CURRENCY] [numeric](27, 9) NULL,
    [DAYS] [numeric](27, 9) NULL,
    [PROVENIENZA] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [USERUPD] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [DATEUPD] [datetime] NULL,
    [EN_VERSION] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AW_FCT_000002_000001] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.000000000)) FOR [DAY_RATE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AW_FCT_000002_000001] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.000000000)) FOR [DAY_RATE_ORIGINAL_CURRENCY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AW_FCT_000002_000001] ADD  DEFAULT ((0.000000000)) FOR [DAYS]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AW_FCT_000002_000001] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EN_VERSION]
GO


(1) I'm sensing a data normalization issue in your table design. I recommend you search for and study articles on "database normalization". (2) Is this a one-time job or a recurring process? If recurring, then I think you also have a process issue, as it looks like you are deduping and combining data, adding new dups, and repeating. It would be better if you gathered and combined new data ahead of time and merge (add or update) into the target table. (3) Does your data have IDs? If so, a GROUP BY xxx_ID (or multiple IDs) would be more efficient than 20+ text columns. If not, see comment #1.

Query plan here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HydaVBp2C

There is a certainly an underlying 'process' point here, however, the process is what it is for now.  There is a potential underlying process change that could prevent the need for doing the GROUP BY and INSERT - but that's for another day.
However, the load (from the execution plan) appears to be driven from the INSERT, not the GROUP BY anyway?

Your query plan suggests that its inserting 52 million rows, twice, once into the first temp table, once into the main table. The first insert has to be sorted because of the group by, and its sorting by almost all the columns, so I assume you don't have an index to help with that. Its not obvious from that query plan which of the 2 inserts is the slower (each sum to 100%), but I would guess the first. There might not be much you can do if you need to group it like that.

The group by is causing ~78% of the first insert, and we don't know how the first insert compares to the second, but my guess is most of it. if you run the query with set statistics time on you should be able to see the proportion of time in each insert.

You probably should rethink what you are doing here : 1. insert from AW_FCT to TEMP. 2. truncate AW_FCT. 3. insert from TEMP back to AW_FCT.  What you are doing here are going to consume more time when the number of rows increases. Why not just create a VIEW ? Make your first GROUP BY query as a VIEW

I have added statistics into the question which may help.

The challenge is that I have a process that creates the duplicate rows, by design.  Each day, duplicate rows are created, which require summation to bring the row count back down.  It's ever increasing, but this is designed to manage the number of rows from not growing as rapidly as it would otherwise, by only retaining one row per combination of text fields.
So a view unfortunately won't work.

Surely you can restrict the process to only recently inserted rows? (And matching rows of course). You shouldn't need to apply it to the entire table every time.

Why not just summarize the rows that are duplicated? Or fix that process

Am I right in thinking the INSERT INTO AW_FCT_000002_000001 is solely to add a unique id and that the layout of both tables is the same apart from the unique identifier?

I'm basically trying to reduce the row count, where all non-numeric fields are the same.
The process correctly creates duplicates.  I could change the process design, but that would be HUGE, and I'll hold on the detail as to why.  The fact is there are duplicates, and they need to be brought back to unique combinations of the text fields, with a SUM on the numeric fields.
The ID generation is only for having an ID, that's not the core reason for doing this.

So every time this runs, it should reduce the row count from, let's say 900,000,000 down to 650,000,000.
The 900,000,000 records is inevitable for now, and this runs every couple of hours.

'INSERT INTO AW_FCT_000002_000001' I didn't think it was. so why not clone the source table, populate it, delete source and rename work table?

not quite , the second insert adds the id I'm suggesting the second insert may not be necessary.

Sorry, hit 'add comment' too soon:
I think you're right - just rename the table at the end, rather than doing an enormous INSERT INTO However, I have learned that the issue is mostly from the GROUP BY (first SQL statement), as opposed to the INSERT So I think the GROUP BY will still be the issue

Incremental benefit I agree, please add table definition as text.

Added create table script.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The last seven columns in your table definition DAY_RATE ... EN_VERSION are neither referenced by your original logic nor preserved when you rebuild the table. Are these columns significant?

Can these columns identify duplicates?

If this runs once each night for 20 minutes, you might consider living with it for now and focus efforts on designing and developing a completely new process to replace it - one that separates daily data from summarized/aggregated data. But if you insist...
If you have the ability to alter the table definition, the current process can be improved if you:

Set column OID as the PRIMARY KEY.
Add a persisted computed column containing a cryptographic hash calculated from the values of the 20+ currently grouped columns.
Add an index in this new column that also includes the two amount columns. (Column OID is also needed, but is implicitly included as the primary key.)
Modify your process to update one of the rows in place and delete any remaining duplicate rows. Single (non-duplicated) rows should not be touched.

Using a single persisted computed column should greatly improve the efficiency of the grouping operation. Indexing that column is even better. Having the amount columns included in that index allows the initial scan and aggregation to be performed using a narrow index scan instead of a wide table scan. Finally, selecting one existing row to update in place saves the need to copy all those other columns and significantly reduces the insert/delete overhead.
Although the persisted computed column and associated index does have some overhead during the initial inserts, I believe this is more than offset by the potential savings.
For the persisted computed definition, the following add-column and index DDL can be used.
ALTER TABLE AW_FCT_000002_000001
    ADD HashColumn AS CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), HASHBYTES(
        'SHA2_256', -- SHA1 may be faster, but is deprecated
        ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), SCENARIO), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), PERIOD), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), DEPARTMENT), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ACCOUNT), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CATEGORY), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CURRENCY), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), PROJECT), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), PARTNERSHIP), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), EMPLOYEE), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), BOOKING_DATE), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ORIGINAL_CURRENCY), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ANALYSIS_COMMENT), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), COMMENT_TYPE), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), NOTE), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ALLOCATION_EXPLAINER), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), PIPELINE_VALUATION_DATE), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), PIPELINE_PROBABILITY), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), TECH_ORIGINAL_USER), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), TECH_ORIGINAL_ORIGIN), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), TECH_ORIGINAL_DATEUPD), 0x)
        + 0x00 + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), DEPARTMENT_VISIBILITY), 0x)
    ))
    PERSISTED NOT NULL

CREATE INDEX IX_AW_FCT_000002_000001_HashColumn
    ON AW_FCT_000002_000001(HashColumn)
    INCLUDE(AMOUNT, ORIGINAL_AMOUNT)
    -- I'm assuming that OID is the PK, so is implicitly included.

The above calculation has a few limitations:

A null byte 0x00 is used to delimit column values, which should be acceptable for columns containing normal text values that do not contain null CHAR(0) characters.
A null column is treated as equivalent to an empty value ''.
Text values hashed exactly as represented, so are case-sensitive, accent-sensitive, etc. (If you need to match case-insensitive values, you can add UPPER() to each value above.)

I expect this should be sufficient for your use case. A more robust expression can be found in this answer. (I also recall having seen an approach that maps all of the columns to JSON or XML and then calculates the hash, but I can't find that right now.)
The following SQL can then be used to consolidate the data:
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
    HashColumn VARBINARY(32) NOT NULL,
    OidToKeep VARCHAR(36),
    CombinedAmount numeric(27, 9) NULL,
    CombinedOriginalAmount numeric(27, 9) NULL
)

SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Find and combine duplicates
INSERT @Temp
SELECT
    F.HashColumn,
    MIN(F.OID) AS OidToKeep,
    SUM(F.AMOUNT) AS CombinedAmount,
    SUM(F.ORIGINAL_AMOUNT) AS CombinedOriginalAmount
FROM AW_FCT_000002_000001 F
GROUP BY F.HashColumn
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2

-- Update the row to be kept
UPDATE F
SET
    AMOUNT = T.CombinedAmount,
    ORIGINAL_AMOUNT = T.CombinedOriginalAmount
FROM @Temp T
JOIN AW_FCT_000002_000001 F
    ON F.HashColumn = T.HashColumn
    AND F.OID = T.OidToKeep

-- Delete the other rows
DELETE F
FROM @Temp T
JOIN AW_FCT_000002_000001 F
    ON F.HashColumn = T.HashColumn
    AND F.OID <> T.OidToKeep

COMMIT

The first statement selects and aggregates the data based on the HashColumn value and also limits results to those HashColumn values having duplicate (2 or more) rows. It then updates one chosen survivor row, and removes the other sacrificial rows.
If you had a date-added column and only need to consider data added after a certain date/time (since last successful run), you could add something like:
WHERE F.HashColumn IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT F1.HashColumn
    FROM AW_FCT_000002_000001 F1
    WHERE F1.DateAdded >= @SinceDateParameter
)

The above should be paired with an index CREATE INDEX IX_xxx ON AW_FCT_000002_000001(DateAdded) INCLUDE (HashColumn).
If you wanted to specifically preserve the row having the earliest date, you could change MIN(OID) AS OidToKeep to something like:
(
    SELECT TOP 1 F1.OID
    FROM AW_FCT_000002_000001 F1
    WHERE F1.HashColumn = F.HashColumn
    ORDER BY F1.DateAdded
) AS OidToKeep

If the above is used, the DateAdded column should be added to the earlier IX_AW_FCT_000002_000001_HashColumn index - CREATE INDEX IX_AW_FCT_000002_000001_HashColumn ON AW_FCT_000002_000001(HashColumn, DateAdded) INCLUDE(AMOUNT, ORIGINAL_AMOUNT). Your DATEUPD or EN_VERSION columns might be candidate substitutes for DateAdded for this use in selecting the earliest row..
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
